# extending base and static resources

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Using Jinja2 but not Flask. Is there a way to retain the extended resources url if you are going x level deep in your navigation?
I have the following in my base.html which gets extended

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/base.css">
```

My styles get extracted to a dist folder on the top level domain. 
here is the yaml

```
- url: /styles
static_dir: dist
```

Going to subpages returns 404 on my status files, which makes sense since I am no longer looking at the same directory tree. But is there a way using some sort of built-in env variable to always have the correct path?

Comment: I think you just want `href="/styles/css/base.css"` (with a leading `/` in the relative URL).

Comment: oh yeah, thanks :D